# Oracle Sqlldr error with column having crlf

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

I am trying to load a '|' delimited file, but it fails because some columns have crlf values.

I converted the text files to xlsx and imported them successfully using SQL Developer.

I noticed that SQL Developer using a Line Terminator option set to "standard: CR LF, CR or LF".

I suspect that I need to set that in my ctl file, but have been unable to find the correct syntax.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot from SQL Developer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As usual, it helps if you post what you have (in this case, control file, table description and sample data). Without it, we have to *guess* and that doesn't have to reflect reality.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id          number,
  3     description varchar2(50));

Table created.
```

Control file (contains sample data):

```
load data
infile *
replace
continueif next preserve(1:1) != "|"
into table test
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols

(
  dummy filler,
  id,
  description 
)

begindata
|1|this is some text 
with no meaning 
at all
|2|some 
more text
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@pdb1 control=test11.ctl log=test11.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Nov 26 21:51:53 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test11.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 this is some text with no meaning at all
         2 some more text

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]** Using piece of code @p3consulting suggested: no difference (at least, not in my 21XE database):

Control file (modified line #2, the `infile` one):

```
load data
infile * "STR X'220D0A'"
replace
continueif next preserve(1:1) != "|"
into table test
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols

(
  dummy filler,
  id,
  description 
)

begindata
|1|this is some text 
with no meaning 
at all
|2|some 
more text
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@pdb1 control=test11.ctl log=test11.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Nov 27 12:34:04 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-283: file processing string "STR X'220D0A'" ignored for INFILE *
Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test11.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result: no difference:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 this is some text with no meaning at all
         2 some more text

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT #2: removed CONTINUEIF]**

```
load data
infile * "STR X'220D0A'"
replace
into table test
<snip>
begindata 
<snip>
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@pdb1 control=test11.ctl log=test11.log

SQL*Loader-283: file processing string "STR X'220D0A'" ignored for INFILE *
<snip>
```

Ah! I should've read the message, Oracle says it all:

> file processing **string "STR X'220D0A'" ignored for INFILE**

So: with a new control file:

```
load data
infile "c:\temp\test11.txt" "STR X'220D0A'"
replace
into table test
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols

(
  dummy filler,
  id,
  description 
)
```

and data in a separate, `test11.txt` file:

```
|1|this is some text 
with no meaning 
at all
|2|some 
more text
```

Loading session:

```
<snip>
Commit point reached - logical record count 1

Table TEST:
  1 Row successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test11.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 this is some text
           with no meaning
           at all


SQL>
```

That looks A LOT better now!

Though, row#2 is missing. Log file doesn't say anything about it:

```
SQL> $type test11.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Nov 27 15:30:39 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Control File:   test11.ctl
Data File:      c:\temp\test11.txt
  File processing option string: "STR X'220D0A'"
  Bad File:     test11.bad
  Discard File:  none specified

 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 50
Bind array:     250 rows, maximum of 1048576 bytes
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Conventional

Table TEST, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: REPLACE
TRAILING NULLCOLS option in effect

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
DUMMY                               FIRST     *   |       CHARACTER
  (FILLER FIELD)
ID                                   NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER
DESCRIPTION                          NEXT     *   |       CHARACTER


Table TEST:
  1 Row successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.


Space allocated for bind array:                 129000 bytes(250 rows)
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:             1
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0

Run began on Sun Nov 27 15:30:39 2022
Run ended on Sun Nov 27 15:30:39 2022

Elapsed time was:     00:00:00.17
CPU time was:         00:00:00.11

SQL>
```

No bad nor discard file:

```
SQL> $type test11.bad
The system cannot find the file specified.

SQL> $del test11.dsc
Could Not Find c:\temp\test11.dsc

SQL>
```

The input file looks like this (when all characters are displayed):

[image]

---

**[FINALLY]**

> p3consulting: 22 is not the hex for | ... it's 7C... but you need to finish the record by |CRLF... your rows end with only CRLF.

Bingo!

Control file:

```
load data
infile "c:\temp\test11.txt" "STR X'7C0D0A'"
replace
into table test
fields terminated by '|'
trailing nullcols

(
  dummy filler,
  id,
  description 
)
```

Test11.txt:

```
|1|this is some text 
with no meaning 
at all|
|2|some 
more text|
```

Loading:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@pdb1 control=test11.ctl log=test11.log

SQL*Loader: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Nov 27 17:11:21 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

Table TEST:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  test11.log
for more information about the load.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID DESCRIPTION
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 this is some text
           with no meaning
           at all

         2 some
           more text


SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot - I believe your response is almost what I need, except I would like to keep the crlf in the data.

Comment: see my answer using STR parameter to INFILE: this solution keeps the CR LF in the inserted data.

Comment: @p3consulting, could you - please - demonstrate it? Either I'm doing something wrong (see edited answer), or it doesn't work. Unless I'm wrong, you copied it from https://datacadamia.com/sql_loader/carriage_return_in_text_field but - did you actually tested it? I'd really love to see you demonstrate it.

Comment: ... but you kept the" continueif next preserve..." which gives opposite instruction...

Comment: Aha! That makes sense, @p3consulting, thank you. I fixed it, loaded data again and no improvement. Why? Because that option is ignored if data is contained in control file (i.e. with `infile *` and data following the `begindata` keyword). Have a look at demo (EDIT #2). Now it looks way better, but - the 2nd row isn't loaded. It wasn't rejected nor discarded. Any idea?

Comment: Could the 2nd row be missed because it doesn't identify the end of the first row since the CRLF are ignored?  How is the "end of record" identified?

Comment: I attached screenshot (from Notepad++) into the answer which shows *all characters* - see CRLFs.

Comment: ... or because there is no CRLF before the EOF...

Comment: INFILE 'target.dat' "STR X'220D0A'"  -  That works, except it only imports 1 row and stops.

Comment: of course: my fault... 22 is not the hex for | ... it's 7C... but you need to finish the record by |CRLF... your rows end with only CRLF.
I tested here and it works.

Comment: I tested it as well, @p3consulting - **congratulations**, now it works. I hope that data to be loaded follow these rules and - if not - can be adjusted so that `|` and CRLF are where expected. Thank you (from me), I learnt something new today.

Comment: So, to recap I should use "STR X'7C0D0A'" and ensure that every row ends with | - is that correct?

Comment: I do not have access to modify the file - so, is there another option other than ensuring that every row ends with |

Comment: I was able to modify the file and add | to the end of each row - but, it still only processes the first row and stops.  It seems that I need to provide a different eol character and have sqlldr recognize it - thoughts?

Comment: Did you follow **everything** I did under the "FINALLY" edit revision in my answer? As you can see, I successfully loaded both records.

Comment: Thank you, @Barbaros - it was with a great help of @p3consulting!

Comment: @Littlefoot I believe I followed everything under the "FINALLY" edit revision of your answer, but only 1 row is inserted.  I will double check today

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
INFILE 'target.dat' "STR X'220D0A'"
```

The terminator_string is specified as either 'char_string' or X'hex_string' where:

'char_string' is a string of characters enclosed in single or double quotation marks
X'hex_string' is a byte string in hexadecimal format that you can get with the cast_to_raw function.

So here X'220D0A' is "|CRLF" and this will keep the "CRLF" in the imported column.